# Accent Character in physical url is not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, isapi

I try to open a link which have accent character in url then it is does not display the page:

**IIS Server** : IIS6
**URL :**  bälle-golf-sitemap.xml
**Error:** The system cannot find the file specified.
**Rewriting:** ISAPI_Rewrite

In II7 this URL is working fine but when we try to access that page on server which have IIS6 then it is not working.

when I use the accent character in virtual URL and rewrite that page to without accent character then it is working fine.

Please advise me what configuration i am missing.

Thanks for your help.